# What is the purpose of using synchronized (Thread.currentThread()){...} in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

I faced the following code in our project:

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread()){
    //some code
}
```

I don't understand the reason to use synchronized  on `currentThread`.

Is there any difference between

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread()){
    //some code
}
```

and just

```
//some code
```

Can you provide an example which shows the difference?

### **UPDATE**

more in details this code as follows:

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
       Thread.currentThread().wait(timeInterval);
}
```

It looks like just `Thread.sleep(timeInterval)`.  Is it truth?

Comment: Off the top of my head I can see no use for this. If the Thread object returned by Thread.currentThread() is static, then it would make sense. There is nothing the Thread source that indicates this and is it horribly bad design anyway.

Comment: generally, this has no sense, but maybe there is other code which synchronizes on different thread, then it interacts with the code you cited.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov сложно)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARBSs.jpg (this code is one behind the _right_ door)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

consider this

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() { // A
            synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
                System.out.println("A");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    synchronized (t) { // B
        System.out.println("B");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

blocks A and B cannot run simultaneously, so in the given test either "A" or "B" output will be delayed by 5 secs, which one will come first is undefined

Comment: That would seem to be a great recipe for a race condition.

Comment: If someone wrote code like this, I would ask him to explain his actions. But yes, this is an example where the synchronization would actually happen.

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev **blocks A and B cannot run simultaneously** Can you   write example with **Thread.sleep** when A will wait B or B will wait A ?

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev thanks. Therefore it is looks like just Thread.sleep().

Comment: @gstackoverflo remove sychronized to see the difference

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev  Yeah I feel difference.  I just try to predict what  developer wanted to do in code)

Comment: just a general question here, is it just me who finds it painful to analyse or maintain code where the opening brackets are not on a new line of their own?

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev  Is it only way ?

Comment: @gstackoverflo Thread.currentThread() is an Object, any object can be used as a lock, so you can do any sycnhronization tricks with cuurent thread object, but as far as I know using a thread as a lock is bad practice

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev I just cannot imagin another situatiot except your answer. (start thread in synchronized section. section monitor is this thread)

Comment: @pnizzle I'm sure you're not the only one, but you are a part of a humble minority. For my purposes, conserving vertical screen space is a cherished virtue.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, assuming that my 'group' is indeed the minority, I would believe that the reason why that would be is because example code like the one above is everywhere on the inter-webs and programmers, especially new ones, are forced to think that that is the standard and yet no, not really. It's hideous, if I am to be polite (nothing to do with the answer, just the bracket style). Well, to each his own I guess..

Comment: @pnizzle It actually happens to be the standard way, codified as Sun's formatting conventions, and as the conventions used in the majority of open-source Java projects. But as always, the more trifling the issue, the stronger the opinions.

Answer (score 9):

Although this is almost definitely an antipattern and should be solved differently, your immediate question still calls for an answer. If your entire codebase never acquires a lock on any `Thread` instance other than `Thread.currentThread()`, then indeed this lock will never be contended. However, if anywhere else you have

```
synchronized (someSpecificThreadInstance) { ... }
```

then such a block will have to contend with your shown block for the same lock. It may indeed happen that the thread reaching `synchronized (Thread.currentThread())` must wait for some other thread to relinquish the lock.

Comment: I cannot imagine this situation. Can you show code example?

Comment: Look at your accepted answer by Evgeniy for a code example.

Comment: Well, as I say in the answer, this is not something you *should* have in your code so Evgeniy's artificial example is as good as it gets. It demonstrates the principle without giving a real-life motivation.

Answer (score 6):

Basically there is no difference between the presence and absence of the `synchronized` block. However, I can think of a situation that could give other meaning to this usage.

The `synchronized` blocks has an interesting **side-effect** of causing a **memory barrier** to be created by the runtime before entering and after leaving the block. A memory barrier is a special instruction to the CPU that enforces all variables that are shared between multiple threads to return their latest values.  Usually, a thread works with its own **copy** of a shared variable, and its value is visible to this thread only. A memory barrier instructs the thread to update the value in a way so that the change is visible to the other threads.

So, the synchronized block in this case does not do any locking <strike>(as there will be no real case of lock and wait situation, at lest none I can think of)</strike>(unless the use-case mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981673/synchronized-thread-currentthread-what-the-sense/22982070#22982070) is addressed), but instead it enforces the values of the shared fields to return their latest value. This, however, is true if the other places of the code that work with the variables in question **also uses memory barriers** (like having the same `synchronized` block around the update/reassignment operations). Still, this is **not a solution** for avoiding race conditions.

If you're interested, I recommend you to read this [article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx). It is about memory barriers and locking in  C# and the .NET framework, but the problem is similar for Java and the JVM (except for the behavior of volatile fields). It helped me a lot in understanding how threads, volatile fields and locks work in general.

One must take into account some serious considerations in this approach, that were mentioned in comments below this answer.

- The memory barrier does not imply locking. The access will still be *non-synchronized* and a subject to *race conditions* and other potential issues one may encounter. The only benefit is the thread being able to read the latest values of the shared memory fields, *without* the use of locks. Some practices use similar approaches if the working thread only *reads* from values and it does only care for them to be the most present ones, while avoiding the overhead of locks - a use case could be a high-performance simultaneous data processing algorithm.
- The approach above is *unreliable*. As per [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981673/synchronized-thread-currentthread-what-the-sense/22982038#comment35095418_22982038), the compiler could eliminate the lock statements when optimizing, as it could consider them unnecessary. This will also remove the memory barriers. The code then will not issue a lock, and it will not work as expected if a lock was meant to be used, or the purpose was to create a memory barrier.
- The approach above is also *unreliable* because the *runtime JVM* can remove synchronization when it can prove the monitor will never be acquired by another thread, which is true of this construct if the code never synchronizes on another thread object which is not the current thread's thread object. So even if it works during testing on system A, it might fail under another JVM on system B. Even worse, the code could work for a while and then cease working as optimizations are applied.
- The intentions of the code as it stays now are ambiguous, so one should use more explicit and expressive means to achieve its effect (see [Marko Topolnik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981673/synchronized-thread-currentthread-what-the-sense/22982038?noredirect=1#comment35095397_22982038) for reference).

Comment: Relying on unspecified side-effects of hardwarde-specific implementation semantics would definitely be ill-advised. The JMM only specifies what happens when another thread acquires *the same lock*.

Comment: Memory barriers without correct synchronization are useless. At the time the barrier is passed, any other thread might be before or after or even in-between reading or writing the shared variables without any control and thus, still produce unpredictable results. That’s why the JVM is allowed to remove `synchronized` blocks which have no effect, thus removing the memory barrier too.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I absolutely agree, if you want that particular effect I have mentioned of, one must use explicit means to applying it.

Comment: @Holger, you are correct. I have updated the answer to reflect yours and Marko's considerations. Of course, it is still unclear if the memory barrier is the purpose of the code, it is just an unreliable side effect

Comment: @Holger, indeed, because of you I hope. Thanks for the input and the upvote!

Comment: @Holger: There are many single-writer-many-reader situations where memory barriers can be useful without synchronization.  For example, an append-only `ArrayList<T>`-style collection would need a memory barrier between the time it copies items to a new array and the time it replaces the old array reference with a new one, but would not require any other synchronization provided the GC and memory model invalidate any cached data associated with reclaimed memory.

Comment: @Holger: To be assured of seeing the most recent data, a reader would need to have a memory barrier "somewhere", but in most cases the main requirement would simply be to ensure that a read of "number of items" can't get hoisted out of a loop, and that code which noticed that the number of items exceeded the array size could do a volatile read of the array reference.  Meeting those conditions should be much cheaper than using synchronization or even making everything volatile.

Comment: @supercat: reading without a memory barrier includes the possibility to read a recent value for list size but out-of-date values for the items. The memory barrier of the writing thread does not prevent this as it’s the *reading* thread holding cached values in this case. You don’t need “synchronization or even making everything volatile” to get a correct behavior but at least one of the offered ways to establish a *happens-before* relationship.

Comment: If list items are not allowed to be nulls, then by the time a reading thread sees that there are supposedly 46 items, the writing thread will have committed 49 items to memory.  It's possible the threading thread will have cached a reference to an array with fewer than 46 items, or will conceivably that a read of item 44 caused a then-empty array slot 45 to be cached, but having the reading thread notice those conditions and impose a read barrier only when necessary would be cheaper than imposing one unconditionally.

Comment: @supercat: To put it simply, no!  You really need to read and thoroughly understand ***why*** double-checked locking is broken. Marko has it correct in the first comment - unless it's on the ***same*** object `synchronized` provides no guarantees about anything.

Comment: @LawrenceDol: Everything depends upon memory models. If a thread that creates an object have sufficient primitives to ensure that the object itself will be physically stored to memory before any reference to it is accessible to any outside thread, the GC will ensure that the memory associated with an object cannot be cached by a thread that has never seen a reference to it, and if threads have a means of forcing a read-barrier if logic detects stale data, those guarantees are sufficient to allow some useful kinds of information exchange between threads without locking.

Comment: @LawrenceDol: For "double-checked" locking to work, it is necessary that the object-creating thread be able to ensure that an object's data is fully written to main RAM before a reference is made accessible to other threads--*an ability not provided by all memory models*, and for reading threads to know that the GC will invalidate cache entries for objects that no longer exist. My point is that memory barriers are useful in the absence of locking if they provide suitable guarantees; obviously their usefulness depends upon those guarantees.

Comment: @supercat: My point is simply that the JMM guarantees a general memory barrier between two threads ***only*** if both threads synchronize on the ***same*** object and to a much lessor extent if they reference the same volatile variable (the latter being with respect only to the variable in question). Period. Making any other assumptions about memory visibility will result in potential bugs on some unspecified JVM on some unspecified hardware. That on most, even all current hardware any `synchronized` happens to flush all CPU caches to main memory is a *side-effect*, not a requirement.

Comment: @LawrenceDol: My point was in response to Holger's claim that memory barriers without correct synchronization [by which I assume he meant monitors/'lock' blocks] are useless; I would claim that memory barriers can be useful in and of themselves even without locking.  Obviously memory barriers would be useless if they don't establish ordering are useless, and Java has no general facilities to create memory barriers, but my point is that they'd be useful if Java were to provide them.

Comment: @supercat: Ahh OK, you failed to stipulate the crucial, "were Java to provide them"; this question is about a Java construct - you are arguing a hypothetical language/MM and I am arguing Java/JMM as it stands today. ***In Java***, there is no such thing as a memory barrier without correct synchronization, because the JMM makes no memory visibility guarantees except when two threads synchronize on the same object or access the same volatile. That any old synchronize happens to work on, e.g. Intel chips is a ***side-effect*** and you should never, ever program to side-effects.

Comment: @LawrenceDol: Sorry I was unclear.  My original point was to Holger, whose comment I interpreted as suggesting that there's no reason for Java to include memory barriers, since they wouldn't be useful without synchronization.  It may have been intended to say that the effects of memory barriers created by Java's synchronization blocks, unlike the C# barriers discussed in the original answer's linked article, are useless to code outside the synchronization blocks *because they are ignored by such code*, but that's not the reason it gave for their uselessness.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing a *recursive mutex*.

i.e. the same thread can enter the synchronisation block, but not other threads.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: Actually, other threads would still be able to enter the synchronization block, they would synchronize on their currentThread, which has a different object monitor.

Comment: Is this answer incorrect? I'll happily remove it if it is. (and actually it is a real touchstone that the -2 for downvotes simply does not compensate +10 for upvotes on an incorrect answer).

Comment: @Bathsheba No, answer is correct, but it does not quite answer OP's question. OP is not asking what is synchronizing current thread is called, it asks when it's used... This could be a great comment though.

Comment: Actually, the answer is incorrect. Since if there is no shared mutex, there is no chance of synchronization happening.

Comment: @Bathsheba Any number of threads can enter; the synchronization is being done on the thread's own monitor.

Comment: @Leri But the thread holding the lock can always re-enter the synch block,irrespective of what the synch block synchs on.

Comment: Also note that mutexes (mutices?) are recursive by default. A thread holding the mutex will be able to enter a synchronized block guarded by that particular mutex. No need to synchronize on current thread.

Comment: @Erik And is not that the point of it? Using recursive mutex you don't need entry point for synchronizing recursive calls.

Comment: @Leri See my comment. Mutexes are recursive by default.

Comment: While adding my -1, I just realized the answer is correct, so I pulled it out. Still it needs an additional explanation or example. A good candidate would be a recursive method being called from the current thread and also from other threads, in the manner of [Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981673/synchronized-thread-currentthread-what-the-sense/22981950#22981950) - just imagine the `run()` method being recursive.