# Difference between synchronized(this) and synchronized(Thread.currentThread())

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

This isn't homework, these are some conceptual queries.

1. What is the difference between `synchronized(this)` and `synchronized(Thread.currentThread())`?
2. Is there any use or advantage of gaining a lock on a `Thread` instance?
   (except for calling methods like `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()`)?
3. Also, is there any situation where `synchronized(Thread.currentThread())` could be put to use? (except for calling methods like `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()`)?

Comment: writing "This isn't homework" does not prove its not homework :) by the way who asked you is it homework? :D

Comment: still looks like a homework :)

Comment: almost same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981673/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-synchronized-thread-currentthread-in-java

Comment: @LaurentiuL. As far as I understood, synchronized(this) would give a lock on the object through which a method is called, whereas synchronized(Thread.currentThread()) would give a lock on the Thread object which is being executed when entering the synchronized block. But i can't figure out the difference between their practical use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you choose to synchronize on is only significant in relation to which *pieces of code* want to take the lock to protect a particular action. Therefore the main functional considerations is to ensure those pieces of code can reference the object.

Functionally, it doesn't matter whether you synchronize on `Thread.currentThread()` or `new Object()` as long as the pieces of code that are using that lock can access the object (bearing in mind that `Thread.currentThread()` will return a different object when run on different threads, which makes it quite awkward to use for locking).

**However**, you should be careful to choose objects to synchronize on in a way that will reduce the potential for bugs. The best scenario is that **only** the code that needs to lock the object for a particular action can access the lock object (so no other code will share it for some other locking scenario that might interfere.)